# Analyzing a java tomcat thread dump using Eclipse Memory Analyzer - erroring out

Tags: java, memory-leaks

So I got a java tomcat heap/thread dump using kill -3  .
The dump seems to go into catalina.out in the form of

```
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.2-b06 mixed mode):

"RMI TCP Connection(2018)-50.28.31.254" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f743cb90800 nid=0x2624        runnable [0x00007f7438ef7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
```

ending with

```
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 570432K, used 315753K [0x00000007d5560000, 0x0000000800000000,     0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 442752K, 71% used     [0x00000007d5560000,0x00000007e89ba460,0x00000007f05c0000)
  70000000,0x000000077848b090,0x0000000780000000)
```

...

I copied and pasted the above (and everything in between).. 
Eclipse errored out with the following error when trying to "Open a dump":

```
Error opening heap dump 'dump2.txt'. Check the error log for further details.
Error opening heap dump 'dump2.txt'. Check the error log for further details.
Invalid HPROF file header. (java.io.IOException)
Invalid HPROF file header.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you `Check the error log for further details`? Also note that you have a _thread_ dump as indicated by the header, not a _heap_ dump. Those are different things and hprof files are the latter (i.e. they are _heap_ dumps).

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing wrong is that this is a thread dump and not a heap dump. The easiest way to do a heap dump instead would be to use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/).

Alternatively, you could use [jmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jmap.html) to create your heap dump e.g.:

```
jmap -dump:file=app.bin 123456
```

which will create a heap dump called app.bin for process id 123456